# Compute this integral (Is there a trick hidden to make it eassier?)

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I need some tips to compute this integral:

$$ \int\,\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^5\sqrt{9x^2-1}}\,dx $$

What I did was express the denominator in the following form:

$$ \int\,\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^5\sqrt{9x^2-1}}\,dx = \int\,\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^5\sqrt{8x^2+x^2-1}}\,dx $$

Then, I made the change $x = \sec{\theta}$, then

$$ \int\,\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^5\sqrt{8x^2+x^2-1}}\,dx = \int\,\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec^2{\theta}-1}}{\sec^5{\theta}\sqrt{8\sec^2{\theta}+\sec^2{\theta}-1}}\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}\,d{\theta} $$

Trying to symplify this expression, I came to this:

$$ \dfrac{1}{4}\int\,\dfrac{\sin^2(2\theta)\cos{\theta}}{\sqrt{8\sin^2{\theta}+1}}\,d{\theta} $$

I feel this integral can be computed using some kind of "trick", but I can't see it. Thanks for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: Let $t=\sqrt{x^2-1}/\sqrt{9x^2-1}$ and you will get a rational expression to integrate.

Comment: [According to Wolfram, the integral does not simplify nicely.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E5*sqrt%289x%5E2-1%29%29dx)

Comment: @EricNaslund Mathematica is not doing too well here. One can actually obtain a result in elementary functions (using, for example, the substitution I propose above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int\,\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^5\sqrt{9x^2-1}}\,dx$$
Let $u=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{9x^2-1}}$, which means that $\displaystyle\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{8x}{(x^2-1)^\frac{1}{2}(9x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}}$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int\,\dfrac{u}{x^5}\,\frac{dx}{du}du$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int\,\dfrac{1}{x^6}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{9x^2-1}}\,\left((x^2-1)^\frac{1}{2}(9x^2-1)^\frac{3}{2}\right)du$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int\,\dfrac{(x^2-1)(9x^2-1)^2}{x^6}\,du$$
By some algebra you will find that $x=\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{u^2-1}}{\sqrt{9u^2-1}}$, so
$$I=\frac{1}{8}\int\,\dfrac{\left(\frac{u^2-1}{9u^2-1}-1\right)\left(9\left(\frac{u^2-1}{9u^2-1}\right)-1\right)^2}{\left(\frac{u^2-1}{9u^2-1}\right)^3}\,du$$
which simplifies to
$$I=-64\int\,\dfrac{u^2}{(u^2-1)^3}\,du$$
Which can be found by the substitution $v=u^2-1$. This gives that 
$$I=2\ln\left(\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right)-\frac{8(u^3+u)}{(u^2-1)^2}$$ You should get an answer by back-substitution. Perhaps a trigonometric substitution like you suggested would have made it simpler but this seemed to work fine.

Comment: I did not get the same integral as you after simplification. I got $8u^2(9u^2-1)/(u^2-1)^3$

Comment: I'm not sure - I used wolfram to compute the intermediary simplification steps. :/

Comment: I symplified as you suggested (NOT on Wolfram), and I obtained: $$ 2\int\,\dfrac{u^2(9u^2-1)}{(u^2-1)^3}\,du $$

Comment: Good, then it is just a constant that differs between our results.

Comment: @mickep Yeah that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a partial fractional decomposition of the discriminant, and see if that approach is of any use.

$$\frac{x^2-1}{9x^2-1} = \frac{1}{9}\cdot\left(1+\frac{4}{3x+1}-\frac{4}{3x-1}\right) \ .$$